# NodeJS Forever not ins

Tags: node.js, forever

Have developed a node app. Would like to install it on my server and get it running 'forever'. So I installed forever as follows:

```
wim@development:~/NodeApp$ npm install forever -g
```

I'm always getting the following back and it never goes back to the prompt:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever
```

The versions I'm using are:

```
wim@development:~/NodeApp$ node -v
v0.10.25
wim@development:~/NodeApp$ npm -v
1.3.10
```

Any idea why it's not installing?

Comment: Did you try installing it as root? `sudo npm install forever -g` ? `npm` needs root rights to install globally...

Comment: Yes, tried is with sudo, but it's exactly the same.

Comment: In that case I am unsure, possibly a networking issue? try `wget https://registry.npmjs.org/forever` to see if you can download it yourself on this machine.

Comment: try run sudo npm install -g --verbose to see the detail messge

Comment: As I'm behind a corporate proxy, I presume the issue is there. Will need to see how I can get around it.

Comment: Here is how I got around it: "npm config set https-proxy <proxyIP>:80"